# Centos kernel-devel not available after install

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, vagrant

I am bit confuse that after `vagrant-vbguest` plugin install `kernel-devel-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64` on my `centos` guest machine

[image]

Why I am not able to search for the same package using

`yum search kernel-devel-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64`

[image]

But when I do `yum install kernel-devel-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64` I got package is already installed

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yum search` searches for the specified *string* in a package's `name`, `summary`, `description` and `url` fields.

Your full RPM package name doesn't appear in any of those fields.

If you wanted to check for a package by name specifically like that then, depending on where you wanted to search, you would either want `yum info`, `yum list`, `repoquery` or `rpm -q`.

- `yum info`, `yum list` query the configured (and enabled) repositories as well as the installed packages
- `repoquery` queries the configured (and enabled) repositories *only*
- `rpm -q` queries the installed packages *only*

Comment: Thanks .. That clarity I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the complete kernel version when searching for a package (`yum search kernel-devel`).

If you need more information attributes including the package version you can:

- run `yum info kernel-devel`
- run `yum list kernel-devel-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64`

note: if you still want to get all versions available in the repos you can run `yum list --showduplicates kernel-devel`

Comment: Ok , But still why `yum search kernel-devel-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64` does not work ?

Comment: ok you need to run `yum list` did not make it clear as my example did not include the version, making an update to highlight the difference

Comment: You don't need `sudo` for `yum info` or `yum list`. You'll just create a user-level cache of the yum metadata when you run them as your normal user.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner making an update with removal of `sudo` (just getting used to run install so sudo is needed)

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me